# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline: different operations depending on which cron triggers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scripted pipeline and I'd like to execute different operations:

- every day: run tests
- every weekend: run very long static analysis task

I know I can define multiple triggers with

```
properties(
    pipelineTriggers([cron("0 12 * * *"), cron("* * * * 6")])
)
```

But I don't know how I can then define the job later

```
if (???) {
    sh "run complex task"
} else if (???) {
    sh "run tests"
}
```

How can I find out which of the cron rules triggered my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can't get to the cron information during the build. TimerTriggerCause contains only information that the build was triggered by timer.

```
node {
    properties([
    pipelineTriggers([cron("* * * * *")])
])
   def timeTriggerCause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.TimerTriggerCause)
   println timeTriggerCause?.getShortDescription()
}
```

Couple of solutions:

- Check date during the build
- Use multiple pipelines. You can separate all the logic into one pipeline with boolean parameter (i.e. RunComplexTask). Other pipelines (triggered by timer) would call this pipeline and pass proper value for boolean parameter.

EDIT: I've added example of multiple pipeline setup

PIPELINE_RUN_COMPLEX_TASK:

```
node {
    properties([pipelineTriggers([cron('* * * * 6')])])
    build job: 'PIPELINE_MAIN', parameters: [booleanParam(name: 'RunComplexTask', value: true)]
}
```

PIPELINE_RUN_TESTS:

```
node {
    properties([pipelineTriggers([cron('0 12 * * *')])])
    build job: 'PIPELINE_MAIN', parameters: [booleanParam(name: 'RunComplexTask', value: false)]
}
```

PIPELINE_MAIN:

```
if(RunComplexTask.toBoolean())
{
    echo "Running complex task"
}
else
{
    echo "Running tests"
}
```

Pipeline main has this boolean parameter I've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
Do you have a link to an example of such a multiple pipeline setup?

Comment: I've added example to my main answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example, that clarifies a lot. The only remaining question is where should I put the various pipeline definitions?
I understand I can not use a single file, the Jenkinsfile, right?

Comment: Yes, you have to create 3 pipeline jobs. And you don't have to create file. You can paste code in Jenkins UI like I did
[here](https://imgur.com/a/nwIaJ9b).

Comment: Unfortunately in my environment I edits through the Jenkins UI are not permanents, I need to be able to specify everything with code/configuration in files.
If you edit the answer to say it's not possible to do just with files in the target repository I'll accept the answer

Comment: Currently you can't achieve that with jenkinsfile. What you can do (and I'm big fan of) is to use [JOB DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin). It let's you maintain configuration of Jenkins' jobs in groovy code.